# Camera Grid Lines iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used camera overlay to implement grid lines when user takes photo. But due to this overlay I'm unable to zoom while taking snap. Is there any options to turn on camera grid lines programmatically.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are implementing the overlay?

Comment: This is not related to XCode! XCode is just an IDE. You could write iOS app with SublimText (to name a famous one), and compile.

Comment: I haven't worked with camera overlays, but I'm assuming they're just a UIView at heart.  Can you set `yourCameraGridOverlay.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`?